# Sort items in a UITableView by date

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sorting, group-by, nsdate

So in my app, I have a `UITableView`, and in the navigation controller there is a button to add a new item.  This than takes you to an add an item screen and when you finish, i use a custom delegate to pass the information from the detail viewController to the main `tableViewController`.  Now that I have the info from delegate, I take the 3 pieces of info and put them in an NSArray in my main Array.  Now my question is, how can I sort the detail items by date.  I have tried (unsuccessfully) 3 times now and I can't seem to figure it out.  The arrays and dictionarys get confusing because they are nested.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

The Delegate Method in the tableViewController class:

```
-(void)finishedAddingFoodItemFromDetail:(NSDate *)date whatWasEaten:(NSString *)whatFood whichMeal:(NSString *)meal{

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

if (!self.theArray) {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"theArray"]) {
        self.theArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"theArray"];
    }
    else{
        self.theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}
[self.theArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dateString, meal, whatFood, nil]];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.theArray forKey:@"theArray"];

[self.tableView reloadData];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This is the file higharchy I was thinking of, but I can't seem to implement it.

```
/*  file higharchy
 *   - theBigDict     //large dictionary holding everything
 *       - MutableArray by day stored as objects of theBigDict
 *       - Array of the meals info:
 *           - Meal type
 *           - Food
 */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods on `NSMutableArray` you can call to sort its contents:

```
– sortUsingDescriptors:
– sortUsingComparator:
– sortWithOptions:usingComparator:
– sortUsingFunction:context:
– sortUsingSelector:
```

Since you have an array of complex objects, you will need to write your own function or comparator and call the appropriate sortUsingXxx: method. Do this before you store the array back into NSUserDefaults and before calling `reloadData:` on your table.

Does this help?

EDIT: Your custom function or comparator will have to pull out the date from the two array elements being compared (passed into your function) and return the appropriate comparison results, e.g. NSOrderedAscending, etc.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I added the additional info just to clarify what it was that your function has to do. If your array was simply an array of say, NSNumbers, then you could sort the array using default comparators. (The SDK knows how to compare NSNumbers). But since your array elements are complex, you have to write the comparator function that pulls out the piece of data from each array element (that is passed into your comparator) by which you want to sort (the date) and compare them and return an appropriate NSOrderedXxx result. Make sense?

Comment: But I want to put each day under a different section heading (the date - sorry if i wasn't clear about that before).  How would I do that once the array is sorted

Comment: Ah! That's a different problem, but not hard to solve. You have to keep an array of section index titles and indices. I usually do this with 2 arrays, whose elements parallel each other. One array has the titles for each section, the other is an array of indices into your actual data array indicating at what index each section starts at. have a look at `UITableView`'s sectionIndexTitlesForTableView method, as well as `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what your saying or how to do it

Comment: Ok, so basically, if you want to have section headings, you have to provide them; it's just another responsibility of the data source. In fact, my last suggestion wasn't correct, for section headers... (For an index, you need to mess with those sectionIndex methods...) Anyway, for section headings, you can provide either an NSString or a UIView through the methods tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: or tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:, respectively. Based on the section, you should be able to lookup somehow (say, in an array) what the correct header title (or whatever) should be.

Comment: ...And, you can create that array of titles when you sort your main data by date: you can pull out the dates you want to use for section headers. Lots of ways to accomplish this, and it depends a lot on how you organize your data, where it's coming from, etc.